# how to use node-rio sourceAndEval?

Tags: r, node.js

Does anyone have an example of how to use the sourceAndEval function with node-rio?
https://github.com/albertosantini/node-rio

I can get the basic example working using just eval, but can't seem to figure out how to source the function and pass in parameters for a custom function.  The documentation online lays out the structure for the call, but I was hoping to find a working "hello world" kind of example with it.

For example:

```
testFunction <- function(a,b) { return a+ b; }
```

saved as a function file at `c:\somepath\testFunction.R`

How could I invoke this with rio's `sourceAndEval` function, passing in parameters `a` and `b` from a node service?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you must have found this but just in case someone else needs help with this, there are examples for `sourceAndEval` in the repos. https://github.com/albertosantini/node-rio/blob/master/examples/ex2.js